# SQL Server splitting a huge partition

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, partitioning

What is the best method to split a huge partition(latestPart) containing about 700 Million rows in SQL Server 2008 R2? The table contains data for 6 months (last 2 quarters) and the only  partition(latestPart) is based on a YYYYMMDD field.

I know that it is a good idea to create empty partitions at both ends.I would like to keep the data movement, logging minimum during the data movement between old and new partitions.

Can I quickly move the first quarter data ( about 350 million rows) in the only partition(lastestPart, about 700 million rows) to a new partition ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48176/splitting-a-large-table-to-improve-performance](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48176/splitting-a-large-table-to-improve-performance)?

Comment: are you on enterprise/datacenter edition or standard?

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for suggesting the link. I would like to leverage the partitioning feature, without moving the data out of the tables as this is a very expensive and time consuming operation. The Log file size increases quite fast and this might lead to other situations (disk space not enough, other read and write transactions on the same table will get impacted)